# Typescript Type - extract required function values from a string (generics)

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got the following `PAGES` and I would like to create helper functions for each to resolve each path. This means replacing the sections with ':'.

The helper functions need to have strict types depending on the params needed to be resolved.

Is there a way of adding a `type` to the below code to only allow parameters the selected function needs? ie. Replace the `any`

Any help would be appreciated.

```
const PAGES = {
  TEST: 'YO/:id/again/:param', // params 'id' and 'param' required.
  TEST2: 'YO2/:hello/:yo' // params 'hello' and 'yo' required.
} as const

type ValidParams = any; //replace 'any' and allow only valid params.

type HelperFunctions<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ( params: ValidParams ) => string }

const createHelperFunctions = <P extends Record<string, string>( pages: P ): HelperFunctions<P> => {
   const pageMap = { ...pages };
   const helpers: Record<any, any> = {};

   (Object.keys(pageMap) as (keyof P)[]).forEach((key) => {

      // only accept valid params.
      helpers[key] = ( params: ValidParams ) => {
         const route = routeMap[key];
         return '' // will call another function to replace params in the route.      
      }
   })

   return helpers as ReturnType<typeof createHelperFunctions<P>>;
}


const helpers = createHelperFunctions( PAGES );

// no errors and return 'YO/value-1/again/value-2'
helpers.TEST({ id: 'value-1', param: 'value-2' });

// no errors and return 'YO2/value-2/value-1'
helpers.TEST2({ yo: 'value-1', hello: 'value-2' });

// should get type error 
helpers.TEST({ yo: 'value' });

// should get type error 
helpers.TEST({ yo: 'value', hello: 'value' });

// should get type error 
helpers.TEST({ yo: 'value', hello: 'value', id: 'value', param: 'value' });

// should get type error 
helpers.TEST({});
```

Comment: Do you want a type error, or do you want a compile error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the `ValidParams` type. Given a string literal `P`, it should generate an object type containing all the params of `P`. We can achieve this using template literal types.

```
type ValidParams<P extends string> = 
  P extends `${string}:${infer U}/${infer R}`
    ? Record<U, string> & ValidParams<R>
    : P extends `${string}:${infer U}`
      ? Record<U, string>
      : {}
```

This type can now be used in the `HelperFunctions` like this:

```
type HelperFunctions<T extends Record<string, string>> = { 
    [K in keyof T]: (params: ValidParams<T[K]>) => string 
}
```

This will give you the strict typing for the `TEST` method.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgQQOIFEDKMC8MDeBYAKBhgBV0SAuGAcgE0B5AegoEsATRgQwHNOWxmAB04AnTgFtqAGhiNGMYWPEQa7ajE5g2NRRPUiApgEcAri0NsAdIWJk0JAExU69B8wAWBgDZeQzAJ4g6nIKohIq1J4%20QRpaNIH6xmYW1gQAvhoqoJBQhIRQ-oIGMABqnF7scGHKADxwMAYAHlAGWirQIvzcAHxYMDbwDc2tbCoABgAkOB1daRRT-ABmBiIwAKppjAtgy6sASmljA8QA-DB7BqAibDVrMjNgPTAAZKXlldUQNXvdxzBU9SaLTaMEm0ygnUec22u3Whz%20p3OlxA11u9whXV%20RGIOKoODSeQIBSKMAAEt4iiIAGImMDAKAscBfEhDYGjJFXG4PbjoyE9XrYHD9bHEADaAGkYPwYABrAyBRakAC6VAAFLplFQyhU2FUlMyJUrugBKLC9bnCgkEQjZaAwYCGTgtcleSk0ukMpl9OqskYqC6cmrc3mY7qq0LcAwQAEwY1UF1u2n0xmQOoC3r4EW22DCSMAWU4gj6QsspdzUZgaQA3MdszAopToxyUTdNP4ZG2Bbhq4Scar6AAjABWlygljl-gg6p4BgLglNnBUqonIEVcGNoqVxssixRKE4wHcquX8tNmAzvZxxBC4C8-g0wGABkEsAAbu9tBqIKkr8QGysIFFCclT6cMvy1D89XCWMzVwBErzrEQQBMFo%20iQlDZ0LID5SVGsRV-GBDCgEwRDAGhgnkAB3FgfHtcovFiEAoE8VZFiTT0yKgEBCOfLwD2KL8pU4zxCOQlpLAI%20CrRxNJjUvHjiNI%20sKQAzIkUUsASEKAwamJAxV3tR1nRU6l2JTL44G6bo8KtQk63-EQVGwB0DCdAwExWd1kyZcNEFQDBjTwwgQjAbiViQxzYm0IiSLIlxGHfLwTAMABaABGLheH4BLymSlKHGoQgHO-OwSFVIV2GcRK8rS6RQiUKrctSgrK0CwkQrCkQIpUTRooMDSaAYNxquanKktS2qipMkryAccqYECRrxvSuqol8Ja8pa2SgoIEIIHcZCvG0SNYD0houpRYVissUr5sWmgRvUbb2vkfbDuO-qYDO8LLqm10AJu8g7pADaDFW7x1oepqnra61dteg6TCOmATq%207Tzoiq7psB%20xgdB8HonxmRKqh8a6o1fHWp2vbEeR1Hvou1Y-sbHGyvxQKgA)

---

I wasn't sure if you want the return type to be strictly typed to be a string literal too. But anyways, here is that monster:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgQQOIFEDKMC8MDeBYAKBhgBV0SAuGAcgE0B5AegoEsATRgQwHNOWxmAB04AnTgFtqAGhiNGMYWPEQa7ajE5g2NRRPUiApgEcAri0NsAdIWJk0JAExU69B8wAWBgDZeQzAJ4g6nIKohIq1J4%20QRpaNIH6xmYW1gQAvhoqoJBQhIRQ-oIGMABqnF7scGHKADxwMAYAHlAGWirQIvzcAHxYMDbwDc2tbCoABgAkOB1daRRT-ABmBiIwAKppjAtgy6sASmljA8QA-DB7BqAibDVrMjNgPTAAZKXlldUQNXvdxzBU9SaLTaMEm0ygnUec22u3Whz%20p3OlxA11u9whXV%20RGIOKoODSeQIBSKMAAcqIRCAAO41Ei9TB-AA%20MAAFCQhsDRjAlit1jAzmt-jAwAYAG4rACUTJgKGaYmAUFpMjAJnEACNecyHtwYMy1SAQF4DJpdTA1SxuPxYFr-OrDaaVT5TSYtAZFvwDNpmQBtAC6WJxppZ3pIvo5IxU3r9YbOfqFOBg3oA0tywDAANYGQKLUi%20qjkkSUmkkZP%20mBpCUAbkJxOKaAxjwugi8nGABgQPlp4ZB2pkAFlu1yE9701RtXmYNry1I-ghB%200GzrsAAiZf0v7soER0FTWUQ1uKzPZmB99GQnppGG8g5jfmshE4zfDEFgnmrJOXnA3-kP4j189Ni2bYdl43z9jIYIIJ%20fbenu8qKkmMhHiAOZ9t0vqHAGga4sKYorH8EpCk%20nLjFeqwAGLQjgb7nIcd7-l0gGtu2nZ7OBO44FBUyUWMvRUAgNaFMUAAS3hFCI5EugqLDgF8xHbhcVw3L2k6Lt09K4P02LEMmqYZlmKG5lQNT0PObwVGwVRKHJpbqSyujKPmFLUiZ3SEZgvQMY2BjNsxIG0qWMj0L0hAEgQhDZNAMDAIYnAtKJXjiZJYDSbJfR1GZikospi5npi3QsqE3AGBAAIwBKVAJUlUlQDJkB1PSvT4NpkWwMIxV9pwgh9Amlh9e1JXltWLWybAUTiaVSJKTUmj%20DIs0afiw3HCy9BqgAVpcUCWEeED2TwBidYIhGcCoLLITmcASn6EqWIsKIoK27gsudWbuU1hLYbI8jgF4-gaMAbaCLAorvNoDkQKkX3jSsEAjlmYbYIVENULN5VYB92lfa1MCUiYLR9HjLRHfD-i%20sNX04oYUAmCIabUME8hUiwTrAOUXixCAUCeKsiw1XVMBQCAuM%20UBxQQ3p3PFETBiWF9D5hTiFafcQ1O02mMMiCop1IjTdMkEJNS1oZMXGvFYkrMlqX1XA6nDWFhI45rKjYKbcUGFVlv87JhWIKgGBVoSIRgMLKyUlrsTaGrdM0AwjCg14JgGAAtAAjFwvD8PH5RJ8nDjUBFo0ixAJheFAqd9M7lh2CQLIJuwzgJ7nqfSKESiNznKf5%20WgfhQQweh4WKLa3E0f0wwbhN132eJynLeFzkxel1ADiVxbWvV%20QDh1zAgQd7Paet1Evj77n3cVsNQA)